# SQL Server Rows to Columns using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to get rows into column using comma delimeted using this but how to achieve this using subquery, I achived that in oracle.

**SQL Server :**

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + email
FROM RDT_USER
SELECT @listStr
```

**Oracle :**

```
 SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E, EMAIL || ',')).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS RECEIVERID 
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT (EMAIL) AS EMAIL
          FROM RDT_USER
        )
```

**OUTPUT Expected :**

```
j1@gmail.com,j2@gmail.com,j3@gmail.com,j4@gmail.com
```

Comment: Kindly show a sample output which u want

Comment: Thanks for reply just check question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX) =
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + email
        FROM    RDT_USER
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')

SELECT @listStr
```

If you just want to select without variables, this should work:

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(
        (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ',' + email
        FROM    RDT_USER
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
        ,1,1,'')
```

Comment: bu tmy question is want to achieve this using sub query.

Comment: This approach is usually used for such tasks when using SQL Server. I don't know why you need subquery because this gets the result that you need...

Comment: you are right but am using query to execute in java environment to execute as query not as function or procedure to have declare key word and other variable